# JavaScript call back in cloudharmony API

Tags: javascript, callback

http://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-google:compute
provided a js [API](https://cloudharmony.com/rum/speedtest-google:compute-api.js), but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

```js
function ch_st_loaded(speedtest) {
    /*
    * CALLBACK OBJECT
    * cloudharmony-speedtest Sample Callback Object
    *
    * This Javascript object demonstrates the callback methods and corresponding 
    * API documentation for cloudharmony-speedtest. All methods in this 
    * object are optional (the speedtest checks if methods exist before invoking).
    */
    var st_callback = function() {

        /*
            * This method is invoked before the speedtest starts. If it returns false 
            * test execution will stop
            * 
            * @param array tests an ordered array representing the tests to be performed 
            * and the test order. Each item in the array is an object with the following 
            * attributes:    
            *   concurrency: (optional) concurrency for downlink/uplink tests - this 
            *     signifies the number of concurrent threads that will be used during
            *     each test iteration. Test result metrics are an aggregation of metrics 
            *     for each thread
            *   duration: estimated test duration in seconds
            *   iterations: total number of test iterations to be performed - including 
            *     warmup iterations
            *   location: (optional) location metadata for the test endpoint - an object 
            *     with these attributes: city, state, country, lat, long. Not present 
            *     for endpoints without location information (e.g. CDN, DNS)
            *   max_size: (optional) maximum size (KB) for uplink/downlink tests
            *   min_size: (optional) minimum size (KB) for uplink/downlink tests
            *   provider_id: identifier of the provider (e.g. aws) - see
            *     https://cloudharmony.com/docs/api#!/api/Get_Providers
            *   region: (optional) identifier of the service region (e.g. us-east-1) - see
            *     https://cloudharmony.com/docs/api#!/api/Get_Service
            *   service: name of the service (e.g. Amazon EC2)
            *   service_id: identifier of the service (e.g. aws:ec2) - see
            *     https://cloudharmony.com/docs/api#!/api/Get_Services
            *   service_type: service type identifier - one of: cdn, compute, dns, paas, 
            *     storage
            *   subregion: (optional) identifier of the provider subregion (e.g. us-east-1a)
            *   type: test type identifier - one of: downlink, uplink, latency, dns
            *   warmup: number of warmup iterations - these precede test iterations and
            *     are excluded from result metrics
            * 
            * @param object types object with keys corresponding with every test type and 
            * values describing associated test parameters. Value objects include the 
            * following attributes:
            *   duration: total estimated duration for all tests of this type in seconds
            *   tests: total number of tests of this type
            * @return boolean
            */
        // var google_compute_test = {
        //     provider_id:"google",
        //     service_id:"compute"
        // };
        // var tests = [google_compute_test];
        // var types = [{type:"downlink"}];
        this.started = function(tests, types) {
            console.log("START CALLBACK");
            console.log(tests);
            console.log(types);
        };

        /**
            * This method is invoked when testing ends or is cancelled
            * 
            * @param boolean complete false if testing was stopped before all tests were 
            * completed (e.g. speedtest.stop() invoked)
            * @return void
            */
        this.stopped = function(complete) {
            console.log("STOPPED CALLBACK: complete - " + complete);
        };

        /*
            * This method is invoked when a new test begins and following each test 
            * iteration. If it returns false, 'test' will be aborted and testing 
            * advanced to the next test
            * 
            * @param object test object representing the test this progress pertains to
            * (see started method API documentation above for object attributes)
            * @param object progress an object describing the the test progress. This 
            * object contains the following attributes:
            *   bytes: total number of bytes transferred for this test
            *   failed: current number of failed iterations. Test will be aborted if 3
            *     iterations fail
            *   iteration: test iteration for this progress (0 if test is starting)
            *   iterations: total test iterations (warmup + test iterations)
            *   progress: completion percentage for this test
            *   remaining: number of iterations remaining (i.e. iterations - iteration)
            *   success: number of successful iterations completed
            *   time_remaining: estimated time remaining for this test in seconds
            *   tests_progress: completion percentage for ALL tests
            *   tests_remaining: number of tests remaining
            *   tests_time_remaining: estimated time remaining for ALL tests in seconds
            *   type_progress: completion percentage for ALL tests of this type
            *   type_remaining: number of tests remaining of this type
            *   type_time_remaining: estimated time remaining for ALL tests of this type 
            *     in seconds
            *   warmup: true if this progress is for a warmup iteration. warmup 
            *     iteration metrics are excluded from results
            * @return boolean
            */
        this.progress = function(test, progress) {
            console.log("PROGRESS CALLBACK");
            console.log(test);
            console.log(progress);
            return true;
        };

        /*
            * This method is invoked when test finishes. If it returns false, testing 
            * will stop, otherwise it will advance to the next test
            * 
            * @param object test object representing the test these results pertains to
            * (see started method API documentation above for object attributes)
            * @param object results an object containing details of the test results.
            * This object contains the attributes below (* attributes present only if 
            * status is not 'failed'). Metrics are milliseconds (ms) for latency or dns 
            * tests, and megabits per second (Mb/s) for uplink or downlink tests:
            *   bytes: total bytes transferred for this test including warmup iterations
            *   fastest*: fastest result metric
            *   failed: number of failed iterations (including warmup)
            *   mean*: mean result metric
            *   median*: median result metric
            *   metric10*: 10th percentile result metric (slowest)
            *   metric25*: 25th percentile result metric
            *   metric75*: 75th percentile result metric
            *   metric90*: 90th percentile result metric (fastest)
            *   metrics*: array containing all result metrics (warmup excluded)
            *   sequence: test sequence number (first test sequence=1)
            *   slowest*: slowest result metric
            *   secure: true if HTTPS protocol used for testing
            *   status: test status - one of: success, partial, failed
            *   stdev*: sample standard deviation for test metrics (warmup excluded)
            * @return boolean
            */
        this.results = function(test, results) {
            console.log("RESULTS CALLBACK");
            console.log(test);
            console.log(results);
        };

        return this;
    };
    var uplinkRedirectUri = "test.html"; // change this to the URI where up.html is accessible on your server
    console.log(speedtest.start(st_callback, uplinkRedirectUri));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script async type="text/javascript" src="http://cloudharmony.com/rum/speedtest-google:compute.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting the js console log something, but except the `speedtest.start` was called and returned true (i.e. 1 was logged), there is nothing else.

I looked at the network tab of the dev tool, a bunch of requests were sent, so the async script seems to be runing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up modifying the http://cloudharmony.com/rum/speedtest-google:compute.js

Code too long to fit here.

Added line `console.log(method+"("+args.length+"):"+JSON.stringify(args));` in    `cb=function(method, args){ ... }`